# Calculate $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ and more

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I'm working on the following exercise on Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*:

> **Exercise 3.3.2**: When $R={\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}$ and $B={\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ with $p \mid m$, show that
> $$
> 0 \rightarrow {\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}} \xrightarrow{\iota} {\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}} \xrightarrow{p} {\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}} \xrightarrow{m/p} {\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}} \xrightarrow{p} {\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow \cdots
> $$
> is an infinite periodic injective resolution of $B$. Then compute the group $\mathrm{Ext}_{{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}}^{n}(A,{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}})$ in terms of $A^{\ast}:= \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}(A, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, show that when $p^2 \mid m$, then $\mathrm{Ext}_{{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}}^{n}({\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}},{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}})={\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ for all $n$.

I have shown that the chain is indeed an injective resolution and worked out the $\mathrm{Ext}$ in the general case. But for the "in particular" part, I got stuck.

**Question 1**: What is the map $\iota$ explicitly? I naively think that the map ${\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow {\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ is more natural, by modulo $p$ further for the residue classes modolo $m$, yet I'm quite confused on how to canonically give $\iota$.

**Question 2**: How to calculate  $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$? It seems that this is the key, but I am quite frustrated calculating this. It seems that any $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is completely determined by $f(1)$. But this is the intuition from "$\mathbb{Z}$-module" and I'm not sure for this case. Moreover, since I'm quite puzzled on **Question 1**, I find it hard to really capture which residue classes in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ play the role of $f(1)$.

**Question 3**: Jumping out of this question, let $m, n$ be divisors of $\ell$, I wonder if there are general "formula"s for $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$? Or even $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}}^{k}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}}_{k}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ for general $k$. I have underestimated the difficulty of calculating all these after trying to solve this exercise. Are there any references that have calculated these?

Thank you all for answering and commenting!

Comment: It is better only to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thank you for your comment. I shall improve my style of posting questions in the future. In this post, the "Question 1-3" are in fact, at least from my own naiive view, closely related, so actually it seems to be a single question with few "sub-question"s, and in this way, I hope to show my attempts. Thank you for your suggestion and I will bear it in mind! :)

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote please, if it is not the problem of "asking only one question at a time"?

Comment: I did not downvote the question, if you want to know this. I know that some people just jump to the next question here if they see  several questions as sub- and subsub-questions of a question. Therefore my advice.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Haha, thank you! I only want to improve my post to let it better fit the site and at the same time useful not only for me, but also for later viewers. Maybe my non-mathematical English is not that well to express my emotion, yet I'm definitely not complaining on either you or the downvoters. Sorry if my words may sound rude or impolite. I definitely not mean that. So sorry if that has made anyone feel not well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**: this map is $1 \mapsto m/p$

**Question 2**: Any map of abelian groups (so $\mathbb{Z}$-modules) $\mathbb{Z}/p \to \mathbb{Z}/m$ is a map of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m$-modules because multiplying by $p$ or $m$ gives $0$. Hence, you only need the maps of abelian groups, which is $p$-torsion. This is clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(m/p)$ (all of the multiples of $m/p$ in the range $0,...,m-1$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean that $$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{mZ}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{pZ}, \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{mZ}) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{pZ}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{pZ}, \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{mZ}) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{pZ}, \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{mZ}) ?$$ Then by the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381891/computing-mathrmhom-mathbb-z-n-mathbb-z-m-as-mathbb-z-module , the final result seems to be $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ since the gcd of $m$ and $p$ is $p$? Sorry for being too silly.